# Accessing jQuery plugin properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a jQuery plugin and I'm calling it like the following

```
$('#element').helpify({
    msg : 'This is my message',
    closeButton: {
        text: "Close this",
        colour: "red"
    }
});
```

Then in the plugin I set up some defaults and use extend to create an object with the parameters like this:

```
var settings = $.extend({
    title: 'Default Title',
    msg : 'Default message',
    closeButton: {
        text: "Close",
        colour: "red",
        btnClass: "pull-right"
    }
}, options);
```

I know I can then access the title by writing **settings.title**, what I'm unsure of is how to access the properties within **closeButton**.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

I can access the properties when I pass some in as in the first code block above, however in the second code block which is setting up some defaults and then using the passed in 'options' object should there be some properties supplied - if I don't pass any properties in and rely on the defaults, the ones within **closeButton** do not work, but the others do, i.e. **msg**

**EDIT 2**
Here is a JS fiddle showing what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/U5W5G/1/

Comment: So I'd like to get the values Close, red and pull-right from text, colour and btnClass respectively

Comment: @Martin: what's the `options` object, and how are you trying to access the `closeButton` properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>Simply use `settings.closeButton.text`</s>

JavaScript properties can be accessed using one of two methods:

- **Dot notation**

  The most common and basic way of accessing properties - however illegal variable names (except for reserved words - they are allowed as property names under ES5) will not work.

  ```
  foo.bar; // OK
  foo.class; // only in ES5 and up
  foo.&^&%^&@&(@&&@; // SyntaxError: yeah, it doesn't work
  ```
- **Square bracket notation**

  When using the square bracket notation, it can take anything - however it will be converted to a string (all object properties in JavaScript are strings):

  ```
  // both are the same
  foo['bar'];
  foo["bar"];

  // this is fine
  foo['&^&%^&@&(@&&@'];

  // this is equivalent to foo["[object Object]"]
  foo[{}];
  ```

Pick your fancy - but unless you need to, it's most likely easier to use dot notation to access JavaScript object properties.

**EDIT:** about your jsFiddle, here's why it doesn't work:

```
var options = {
    // Passing these options in
    msg: 'This is my message',
    closeButton: {
        text: "Close this",
        colour: "red"
    }
},
    // These are the defaults if none are passed in
    settings = $.extend({
    title: 'Default Title',
    msg: 'Default message',
    closeButton: {
        text: "Close",
        colour: "red",
        btnClass: "pull-right"
    }
}, options);
console.log(settings.closeButton.text);
console.log(settings.closeButton.colour);
console.log(settings.closeButton.btnClass);
/*
    settings.closeButton.text
    settings.closeButton.colour
    settings.closeButton.btnClass
*/
```

When you're calling `$.extend()`, any properties in the later arguments will replace those in the earlier ones.  In this case, your `closeButton` property in your `$.extend()` call is being replaced by the one in `options`, since the arguments was given later.

Here's an example of this in action:

```
var a = { foo: 'bar' };
var b = { foo: 'baz' };
var c = $.extend(a, b);
var d = $.extend(b, a);

console.log(c.foo); // baz (b was last argument)
console.log(d.foo); // bar (a was given last)
```

To solve this issue, either swap the arguments, or (in this case acceptable) perform a deep copy, by prepending the arguments with `true`:

```
$.extend({ a: { b: 1, c: 2 } }, { a: { b: 3 } }).a; // { b: 3 }
$.extend(true, { a: { b: 1, c: 2 } }, { a: { b: 3 } }).a; // { b: 3, c: 2 }
```

Comment: Ah I see thanks for that. So in this case, when not in closeButton, if I don't supply a property, i.e. title, the default title is used, but within the closeButton object, the whole object is being replaced, therefore the btnClass doesn't exist, is this the case?

Comment: @Martin: indeed, the entire object is replaced - jQuery has no idea at that point that that was your intention.

Comment: Ah thank you! So in that case, there would be no simple way to define a default and therefore a property should always be passed in if I want a property to always be present?